# How to use len() and split() to combine first few strings while keeping the last string alone in a list?

Tags: python, list, split

From `['The', 'range', 'of', 'number', 'is', 'to']` to `['The range of number is', 'to']`

How to combine the first 5th strings into one string while keeping the 6th one alone?

With `len()` and `split()` method.

Comment: `[' '.join(words[:-1]), words[-1]]`

Comment: `" ".join(words).rsplit(maxsplit=1) if len("i") == 1 else ""`

Comment: @Sayse When do you expect `len("i")` not to be 1..?

Comment: @AKX - Never, the op just said they needed to use `len`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not exactly with those methods, since you don't need them.

```
>>> x = ['The', 'range', 'of', 'number', 'is', 'to']
>>> [" ".join(x[:-1])] + [x[-1]]
['The range of number is', 'to']
```

The idea is to join all strings but the last with a space, then append the last word as a list.

Another option would be to use `join` and `rsplit`, which is arguably easier to read:

```
>>> " ".join(x).rsplit(" ", 1)
['The range of number is', 'to']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
>>> var = ['The', 'range', 'of', 'number', 'is', 'to']
>>> [" ".join(var[:5]), " ".join(var[5:])]
['The range of number is', 'to']
```